# Printing in R - PCA rotation components

Tags: r, pca

I did a PCA in R and I am trying to print the rotation components. I was pretty much trying to understand a snippet I found online and I would really appreciate if somebody could help me with it. Please see below the snippet I found online:

```
    require(stats) 
    prcomp(top2, scale=TRUE) 
    summary(prcomp(top2, scale=TRUE)) 

    for (i in 1:15) { 
    top4[[i]] <- sort(survey.prcomp$rotation[,i], decreasing=TRUE)[1:4]} 
    top4
```

I am trying to print top 15 principal components and I get the "top4 object not found error". I am pretty new to R and would appreciate it if somebody could please explain it.

The snippet can be found at  https://www.casact.org/pubs/forum/10spforum/Francis_Flynn.pdf

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you found does not work because there is no declared "survey.prcomp" object. "top4" is missing as well. I assume the authors missed this line:

```
survey.prcomp <- prcomp(top2, scale=TRUE)
```

And also this one:

```
top4 <- list()
```

Then, if your aim is to get first 15 rotation vectors, you can do so with `survey.prcomp$rotation[,1:15]`

The snippet you pasted does something different. It returns, for each of 15 main principal components, top 4 variables that have the most influence on the loadings (rotations).

Comment: No, I am still getting the "top4 object not found error" even after the declaration.

Comment: I edited my answer. Seems like you need to declare top4 as well (do this before the for loop).

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet you pasted a series of variables are accessed but never assigned hence the error.

`top2`, `survey.prcomp` and `top4` are never assigned, in the document you have attached the author seem have omitted those lines.